# Shannon-Nyquist theorem reconstruct 1Hz sine wave from 2 samples

Tags: fourier-transform, nyquist

Lets say I want to set the minimal sampling rate to reconstruct a 1Hz sine wave, according to the Nyquist-Shannon theorem that states that the maximum recoverable frequency is Fs/2 i.e. we must sample the signal 2 times the maximum frequency.

It seems obvious that the limit is a sampling frequency of 2Hz. Lets even say I interpret it as *just* more than 2Fs, lets say 3Fs. This would imply that 3 samples is enough.

So, in Matlab i generate:

```
f=1;%my 1Hz freq
Fs=2*f+1;%=3 =>a bit more than the Nyquist freq
t = linspace(0,1,Fs);
y=sin(2*pi*f*t);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(t,y);
title('sin(2*pi*1*t)');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(abs(fft(y)));
title('abs(fft(y))');
```

The ''sine'' does not even go back up to 0, not even mentioning that even if it did it would be a saw-tooth wave rather than a sine but i guess that is not the problem.

What am I missing, why do I need at least 4 samples rather than 2?

I think this is important to understand the theorem 'in practice'.

[image]

Although even with 4 samples the spike in the FT is wrong, it is at 3 rather than 2 (2 is the 1Hz since the first would be the DC freq)
[image]

[image]

In fact I need 5 samples to get finally this spike at 2 in the FFT! Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your **observation interval** which creates the main problem.

Your reasoning based on the Nyquist sampling theorem is ok; of course with a pure sine wave at the exact Nyquist frequency you will have troubles and therefore it's wise to relax the sampling frequency (slightly) above that of Nyquist rate, such 2.2 Hz instead of a strict 2 Hz... So this is one problem you will practically have.

But your main problem that appears on the FFT plot is about the spectral resolution due to short observation interval. Mainly with two samples (or one second observation of a 1 Hz sine wave) your FFT resolution will be limited to even less than one Hz. Please search the site for PSD, spectral resolution, FFT bin frequency to get a better understanding of spectral analysis of practical windowed data.

In order to see sharp frequency peaks (ideally impulses) in the FFT output of your sine wave, you should increase the spectral resolution, which requires you to increase the observation interval.

I have modified and also expanded your code to see the result of ideal sinc based interpolator on the (near) critically sampled data. Note that I've mereley included a *digital simulation* of ideal sinc based interpolator (not the simulation of analog interpolator) to see that it would indeed reconstruct the pure sinudosidal from its given samples taken at close to Nyquist rate. Note that for the **ideal** sinc interpolator to work, the original signal should strictly be **bandlimited**, or at least sufficiently so, which will have a lot of consequences on the success and efficiency of interpolation.

```
f  = 1;                % 1 Hz. sine wave...
Fs = 4.2*f;            % sampling frequency Fs = 2.2*f  ; a bit more than the Nyquist rate.
Td = 25;               % duration of observation ultimately determines the spectral resolution.
t  = 0:1/Fs:Td;        % observe 25 seconds of this sine wave at Ts = 1/Fs
Td = t(end);           % get the resulting final duration
L  = length(t);        % number of samples in the sequence
M = 2^nextpow2(10*L);  % DFT / FFT length (for smoother spectral display, not better resolution! )

x = sin(2*pi*f*t);     % sinusoidal signal in [0,Td]
%x = x.*hamming(L)';   % hamming window applied for improved spectral display

% Part-II : Approximate a sinc() interpolator :
% ---------------------------------------------
K = 25;                  % expansion factor
xe = zeros(1,K*L);       % expanded signal 
xe(1:K:end) = x;

D = 1024*8;
b = K*fir1(D,1/K);     % ideal lowpass filter for interpolation

y = conv(xe,b);
yi = y(D/2+1:D/2+K*L);

subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t,x);
title(['1 Hz sine wave sampled at Fs = ',num2str(Fs),' Hz, Duration : ', num2str(Td), ' s'])
%xlabel(' time [s]');

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(linspace(-Fs/2,Fs/2-Fs/M,M),fftshift(abs(fft(x,M))));
title(['magnitude of ', num2str(M), '-point DFT / FFT of y[n]']);
%xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');


subplot(3,1,3)
plot(linspace(0,Td,length(yi)),yi);
xlabel('approx simulation of ideal sinc interpolation');
```

Below is a plot for the result of interpolation from a set of near critical sampling.

[image]

And below is the same simulation with a more relaxed sampling, as you can see the interpolator performs much better for this set of improved samples (consequence of better bandlimitedness)

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: Maybe just a complementary question about the 'smoothness', why is the 'sawtooth' considered OK? (e.g., for audio, is there some kind if smoothing taking place, e.g. when Fs=44.1KHz or even we could say 8KHz, less, high frequencies will look like these sawtooth (always talking about pure sines), ?

Comment: @Machupicchu there is no sawtooth. It's your mis interpretation of the available sample points, based on an implied simple crude linear interpolation applied to view them on the plot. If you connect the sample points with regard to ideal sinc based interpolation there won't be a sawtooth but a pure sinusoidal appearing.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so is it correct to say that I used the "wrong interpolator" to display my wave, and that I should have used a sinc interpolator?

Comment: @Machupicchu That linear interpolator is the default mode used by many (indeed all ?) graphics display packages to plot continuous seeming functions in the simplest sense. It's not your fault, but yes if you used an ideal sinc based interpolator to fill in the intermeidate pixels, then you would get a sine curve instead of the sawtooth...

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, great job.

Comment: @Machupicchu oh it's nothing, thanks for your words ;-)

Comment: Well you are a good teacher, (and I am a PhD student)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way I might (occasionnaly) ask you directely some questions related to signal processing?

Comment: @Machupicchu yes you can of course... You can send me messages here, or we can have chat too. But it's always better to ask it as a new question here so that other people can also help.

Comment: oh great! Well I would have a question stemming from this one ... how to implement the sinc interpolation for such a sine wave ? (I have trouble understanding this) -> I will create a new question on this ... and maybe you can answer ;)

Comment: @Machupicchu ok good ;-) just a reminder; here our philosophy is to help people when / where they stuck, not doing their own part of work ;-)

Comment: yes of course I am not asking you to do the work, just to help me understand some concepts of signal processing

Comment: @Machupicchu I have added what you ask for; also changed the code a bit. Have a look at it ;-)

Comment: thanks. Maybe let me add an obvious "question" (but I like to confirm, repeat, things). To rephrase the SHannon-Nyquist thm in terms of required number of data points, we could say : the minimum number of samples needed to construct a sine wave of frequency f is 2*f, e.g. to construct a sine wave of 1MHz in Matlab we need at least 2*10^6 data points (but preferably 3*10^6 datapoints total lets say, 3 is more than 2, since we can't have a fractional number of samples), and that could be interpreted as a sine of freq 1MHz if the 3*10^6 data points are considered as the points sampled in 1second.

Comment: I know its a bit convoluted how I said it, but its just to confirm my understanding through my point of view - if you see what i mean.

Comment: @Machupicchu Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem states that a lowpass signal should be **bandlimited** in order to be sampled without aliasing, and the minimum sampling **frequence** is twice the bandwidth. It doesn't say anything about the number of samples which is inideed **infinite** as any finite length signal cannot be strictly bandlimied. It should have infinite duration. If you truncate a sine wave, its bandwidth becomes infinite; this result is known as **time-bandwith** property of Fourier transforms; the shorter the duration of a signal, the larger its bandwidth; and vice versa.